# using if-else logic to compute different values of new vectors in a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

Here's a data frame called `results`:

```
results <- data.frame(cbind(tot=c(3,4,3,2,1,1,3,0),
                              a=c(0,1,2,2,0,1,1,0),
                              b=c(3,3,1,0,1,0,2,0)))
```

Each row includes a value of `tot` equal to the sum of `a` and `b`.

I need to create vectors `a_prop_tweak` and `b_prop_tweak` and append them to this data frame. If `a`, and `b` are greater than zero, these two new variables are computed one way (for `a`, I divide `a` by `tot` and add `0.025`; for `b`, I divide `b` by `tot` and subtract `0.025`). I compute the values differently if only `a` is zero (`b_prop_tweak=b/ntot`; `a_prop_tweak=0`). If only `b` is zero, the two variables should be computed another way (`a_prop_tweak=a/ntot`; `b_prop_tweak=0`). If both `a` and `b` are zero, the new variables should also equal zero.

Here's what the revised data frame `result` should look like:

```
results <- data.frame(cbind(tot=c(3, 4,     3,         2, 1, 1, 3,         0),
                              a=c(0, 1,     2,         2, 0, 1, 1,         0),
                              b=c(3, 3,     1,         0, 1, 0, 2,         0),
                   a_prop_tweak=c(0, 0.275, 0.6916667, 1, 0, 1, 0.3583333, 0),
                   b_prop_tweak=c(1, 0.725, 0.3083333, 0, 1, 0, 0.6416667, 0)))
```

Note that `a_prop_tweak` and `b_prop_tweak` will sum to 1 unless `tot` equals zero.

The incorrect code I wrote to accomplish this task is working in a way I do not intend:

```
if(results$a > 0 && results$b > 0){
  results$a_prop_tweak <- results$a / results$tot + 0.025
  results$b_prop_tweak <- results$b / results$tot - 0.025
}else if(results$a > 0 && results$b == 0){
  results$a_prop_tweak <- results$a / results$tot
  results$b_prop_tweak <- 0
}else if(results$a == 0 && results$b > 0){
  results$a_prop_tweak <- 0
  results$b_prop_tweak <- results$b / results$tot
}else{
  results$a_prop_tweak <- 0
  results$b_prop_tweak <- 0
}
```

Here's the output, which appears to correctly compute b_prop_tweak (except when `tot`, `a`, and `b` are all zero):

```
> results
  tot a b a_prop_tweak b_prop_tweak ab_prop_chk
1   3 0 3            0    1.0000000           1
2   4 1 3            0    0.7500000           1
3   3 2 1            0    0.3333333           1
4   2 2 0            0    0.0000000           1
5   1 0 1            0    1.0000000           1
6   1 1 0            0    0.0000000           1
7   3 1 2            0    0.6666667           1
8   0 0 0            0          NaN           0
```

I'm clearly thinking through this incorrectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer already notes you're evaluating vectors. If you want to stick with nested `if` and `else`, you can just use `ifelse`. `results$a_prop_tweak <-
  with(results, ifelse(a > 0 & b > 0, "a", ifelse(a >0 & b == 0, "b", ifelse(a == 0 & b > 0, "c", "d"))))`. With `if` statements you would have to apply them to each row of the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`, using `rowwise` and `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

results %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate( a_prop_tweak=case_when( 
               a > 0 & b > 0 ~ (a/tot) + 0.025, 
               a == 0 & b != 0 ~ 0, 
               a != 0 & b == 0 ~ a/tot, 
               a == 0 & b == 0 ~ 0 ), 
          b_prop_tweak=case_when( 
               a > 0 & b > 0 ~ (b/tot) - 0.025, 
               a == 0 & b != 0 ~ b/tot, 
               a != 0 & b == 0 ~ 0, 
               a == 0 & b == 0 ~ 0 ) ) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 5
    tot     a     b a_prop_tweak b_prop_tweak
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     3     0     3        0            1    
2     4     1     3        0.275        0.725
3     3     2     1        0.692        0.308
4     2     2     0        1            0    
5     1     0     1        0            1    
6     1     1     0        1            0    
7     3     1     2        0.358        0.642
8     0     0     0        0            0
```

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes helps to carefully step through your code. You are evaluating vectors in stead of the row per row evaluation you are trying to accomplish. And by doing this you always end up in this part of the if statement:

```
else if(results$a == 0 && results$b > 0){
  results$a_prop_tweak <- 0
  results$b_prop_tweak <- results$b / results$tot
```

There are quite a few ways to do what you want to do, I'll try and post one of them later. Just wanted to show you what is going wrong.

```
> results$a
[1] 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 0
> results$b
[1] 3 3 1 0 1 0 2 0
> results$a > 0 && results$b
[1] FALSE
> results$a > 0 && results$b
[1] FALSE
> results$a == 0 && results$b > 0
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This response really clarified things. I wanted to operate on the entire vector; but my logical call yielded an atomic result. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, try testing what gets returned with a statement like `results$a>0`.  You'll be looking at the entire column, not just each row at a time.  I would handle this by subsetting the columns just to the particular cases you're interested in:

```
#Create the data frame
results <- data.frame(cbind(tot=c(3,4,3,2,1,1,3,0),
                            a=c(0,1,2,2,0,1,1,0),
                            b=c(3,3,1,0,1,0,2,0)))

#create the new columns and initialize to 0
results$a_prop_tweak <- 0
results$b_prop_tweak <- 0


#Deal with cases where both a and b are >0
results$a_prop_tweak[results$a >0 & results$b >0] <- results$a[results$a >0 & results$b >0] /
  results$tot[results$a >0 & results$b >0] +0.025
results$b_prop_tweak[results$a >0 & results$b >0] <- results$b[results$a >0 & results$b >0] /
  results$tot[results$a >0 & results$b >0] -0.025

#If a>0 but b==0:
results$a_prop_tweak[results$a >0 & results$b == 0] <- results$a[results$a >0 & results$b == 0] /
  results$tot[results$a >0 & results$b == 0]
#No need for a b_prop_tweak since it's already 0 by default

#If a==0 and b>0
results$b_prop_tweak[results$a == 0 & results$b > 0] <- results$b[results$a == 0 & results$b > 0] /
  results$tot[results$a == 0 & results$b > 0]
```